# Is it possible to do something with the pr utility's footer?

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

By default, **pr** prints a five-line header with the date, file name and page number and an empty five-line footer / trailer. While reading about how the data in the header can be manipulated I was wondering if anything can be done with the footer. Is the footer necessarily empty, or is it possible to for instance swap the header and footer? Or, is it possible to omit only the footer (I'm aware the -t option will omit both)?

My guess is that the answer is "no" and that the footer merely exists because printers need margins - but I just like to check (and understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is several questions.  Here are a few answers:

- the footer is used because not all printing devices (such as ordinary terminals) support a form-feed function.
- the `pr` from GNU coreutils does [not document](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) any way to set text in the footer.  (I recall long ago using `pr` with some system which did, but a check with a suitably antique version, e.g., [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/pr-1.html#scrolltoc), does not show this).
- none of the options for `pr` hint about swapping header and trailer.
- the `pr` manual page documents both `-t` and `-T` options which both eliminate header and trailer.  The latter also omits form-feeds.
- printers do not "need margins".  Printing-terminals may not have implemented form-feed, so some workarounds were made to address low-cost printers / printing-terminals.  For your amusement, see [this page](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#repaginator).

The `pr` command, by the way, is a standard [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/pr.html) command.  The standard does not mention footer text, but its [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/pr.html#tag_04_101_18) goes into some detail regarding differences between implementions, in particular the way form-feed was handled.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I like the "repaginator"!